# Sublime Text - formatting for code alignment

Tags: alignment, sublimetext, code-formatting

I am a new coder using Sublime Text. I would like to format the line to have equal spacing as that picture below. How can I do that?

[image: image of aligned code]

```
    $Fullname    = $_POST['fullname'];
    $password    = $_POST['password'];
    $username    = $_POST['username'];
    $tel         = $_POST['tel'];
    $address     = $_POST['address'];
```

Comment: Protip: don't. If the length of the longest key changes, your diff now covers the whole map.

Comment: you meant I should not do that? Because I think it can make my code more clearly.

Comment: How would it look if you had var like `$really_long_var_that_breaks_it`?

Comment: @mxmissile if that happens, you can simply reformat the code block to add more spaces. There are tools for Sublime to do that, as I detail in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Alignment`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Alignment) package is probably what you're looking for, although there are [many other plugins](https://packagecontrol.io/search/align) that perform similar functions with various other options. `Alignment` is pretty straightforward, aligning on `=` with at least one space before it. There are also a number of optional preceding characters, so alignment also works with tokens like `!=`, `>=`, `~=`, etc.

[`VAlign`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/VAlign) is a plugin based off `Alignment` that has some additional options available, such as automatic detection of code to be aligned.